# Dwarf Fortress: Masterwork Mod - Prayer Labor

Tags: dwarf-fortress, mods

Pretty straightforward question. What labor is used for the prayer dwarves? I believe it is strand extraction, but my dwarves that have it enabled won't pray. I just want to know so I can be sure that it is something I'm doing that is unrelated to the mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prayer is, indeed, the job formerly known as strand extraction.

Prayer is also performed at one of the religious buildings; dwaves don't just pray anywhere. This is going to sound silly, but have you built any of them? In version ☼6.2☼, the simplest of them, the [Shrine of Armok](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Masterwork:Shrine_of_Armok) [b]-[w]-[alt-H] only requires 2 blocks. In previous versions, it also required candelabras.

If a religious building does exist, the question becomes 'why aren't my dwarves using a workshop?', and the usual checklist applies: are other jobs interfering, is access available, are there any missing reagents, do burrows get in the way, etc.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. You were right, I had put down a bunch of religious buildings months ago, but they still hadn't been built. It will work now, thanks for the help.